# Unordered list in <div> tags

Tags: spring, html, html-lists

Using unordered list `<ul>` tags inside `<div>` creates trouble for me and I am looking for alternatives.

```
firstpage.para1=   <ul><li>item1<li/><//ul> 
secondpage.para1=   This is simple para,not a list.
```

Problem is : my list is actually defined in a spring properties file 
and dynamically resovled in a JSP file using

```
<div id="somestyle">
<spring:message code={pagename}."para1">
</div>
```

Since `{pagename}` can have any value, I cant change code.I cant think of any alternative.
I use  to divide whole page into left and right columns.
Left side has some image and right side has this para1.
Should I find alternativ of `<div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code detects html tags in messages from properties file and rendering it.
I dont have htmlEscape="false" set but it shows list of separate lines. 
Problem is -incorrect rendering(will not show bullets,wrong font ) as it is being used inside .

Now i have to use  to divide whole screen into left and right sides so i cant avoid

```
<div style="width:60%;float:right;"> 
<p><spring:message code="${pageName}.para.1" htmlEscape="false"/></p>

</div>
```

and my message ${pageName}.para.1 is dynamically coming from properties file So it could have html tags or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are several failueres:

first the correct syntax would be:

```
<spring:message code="${pagename}.para1">
```

second s[pring message will escape the output by default,](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.message) so you need:

```
<spring:message code="${pagename}.para1" htmlEscape="false">
```